# With a Python decorator that adds a named argument, is it possible to provide a correct type annotation?

Tags: python, types

Suppose I have this decorator `wrap_with_id` and use it on `func`:

```py
P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def wrap_with_id(fn: Callable[P, R]):
    def wrapper(id: str, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        all_ids.append(id)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@wrap_with_id
def func(x: int, y: int) -> str:
    ...

func
```

When I use pylance or pyright, it knows that the resulting `func` has the following signature:

```py
(function) def func(id: str, x: int, y: int) -> str
```

However, notice that `wrap_with_id` did *not* have a return type annotation. Is it possible to add an annotation so that the type checker knows that the first argument has the name `id`?

The closest I have been able to get is with `Callable[Concatenate[str, P], R]`, but it's not quite right. If I add that annotation, like so:

```py
P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def wrap_with_id(fn: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[Concatenate[str, P], R]:
    def wrapper(id: str, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        all_ids.append(id)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@wrap_with_id
def func(x: int, y: int) -> str:
    ...

func
```

Then pylance/pyright knows that the first argument is of type `str`, but it does not know that it has the name `id`. This is what it thinks the signature is:

```py
(function) def func(str, x: int, y: int) -> str
```

This is a problem because then if I call the function like this, it thinks there's an error, when in fact it's fine:

```py
func(id="abc", x=4, y=5)
```

Comment: The idea to support the concatenation of a keyword argument was rejected in [PEP-612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#concatenating-keyword-parameters) but may be added in the future "if there is sufficient demand".

Answer (score 2):

To make a fully defined function signature (not just the types but also the variable names), I saw a hint from https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols.

> ## Callback protocols
>
> Protocols can be used to define flexible callback types that are hard (or even impossible) to express using the `Callable[...]` syntax, such as variadic, overloaded, and complex generic callbacks. They are defined with a special `__call__` member:
>
> ```py
> from typing import Optional, Iterable
> from typing_extensions import Protocol
>
> class Combiner(Protocol):
>     def __call__(self, *vals: bytes, maxlen: Optional[int] = None) -> list[bytes]: ...
>
> def batch_proc(data: Iterable[bytes], cb_results: Combiner) -> bytes:
>     for item in data:
>         ...
> ```

> Callback protocols and `Callable` types can be used interchangeably.

Using a protocol class's `__call__` and `ParamSpec`, we can get the autocomplete to display your new variables while passing through the original function's shape. Hovering over the final function currently displays the protocol class name. (Would be nice to have the original name pass through!) Autocomplete displays the expected parameter names, types and the function return type.

```py
from typing import Callable, Generic, ParamSpec, Protocol, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

all_ids: list[str] = []

class PrependIdParam(Generic[P, R], Protocol):
    def __call__(self, id: str, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        ...

def wrap_with_id(fn: Callable[P, R]) -> PrependIdParam[P, R]:
    def wrapper(id: str, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        all_ids.append(id)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@wrap_with_id
def func(x: int, y: int) -> str:
    ...

# Hover shows: `(function) func3: PrependIdParam[(x: int, y: int), str]`
# Autocomplete signature shows: `(id: str, x: int, y: int) -> str`
func("id", 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the caller will need to know that `func` takes an additional argument at call time anyway, I would include the parameter in the original definition of `func`, even if the original body doesn't use it. (Note that the function author must be aware that the decorator is adding an parameter named `id`, so that they don't inadvertently add their *own* conflicting `id` parameter, so there's little gained by not being explicit.)

You can still use `ParamSpec` (in conjunction with `Concatenate`) to ensure that the decorated function *does* have an initial `str`-typed parameter in addition to whatever other parameters the function defines.

```
def wrap_with_id(fn: Callable[Concatenate[str, P], R]) -> Callable[Concatenate[str, P], R]:
    def wrapper(id: str, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        all_ids.append(id)
        return fn(id, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@wrap_with_id
def func(id: str, x: int, y: int) -> str:
    ...

func("foo", 3, 5)
```

If you really do want the signature to change, then

```
def wrap_with_id(fn: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[Concatenate[str, P], R]:
    def wrapper(id: str, / *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        all_ids.append(id)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@wrap_with_id
def func(x: int, y: int) -> str:
    ...

func("foo", 3, 5)
```

I think the only thing I've changed here is to make `id` a positional-only parameter, eliminating the option of `foo(id="...", ...)` as a legal call. Whether that helps PyCharm (or is a restriction you want to allow) is an open question.